# How do I preserve continuous (1,2,3,...n) ranking notation when ranking in R?

Tags: r, ranking, rank

If I want to rank a set of numbers using the minimum rank for shared cases (aka ties):

```
dat <- c(13,13,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,17,22,45,46,112)
rank(dat, ties = 'min')
```

I get the results:

```
 1  1  3  4  4  4  4  4  4 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

However, **I want the rank to be a continuous series consisting of 1,2,3,...*n*, where *n* is the number of unique ranks**.

Is there a way to make `rank` (or a similar function) rank a series of numbers by assigning ties to the lowest rank as above  ***but*** instead of skipping subsequent rank values by the number of previous ties to **instead continue ranking from the previous rank**?

For example, I would like the above ranking to result in:

```
1  1  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do it using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dense_rank(dat)

 [1] 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

if you don't want to load the whole library and do it in base r:

```
match(dat, sort(unique(dat)))

 [1] 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Perfect. I was just about to update your answer with that code for people (like me) that prefer to stick with base R. Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @jalapic.

Comment: IMHO, you should better give two solutions as two separate answers to help with the voting

Answer (score 5):

Use a `factor` and then bring it back to `numeric` format:

```
as.numeric(factor(rank(dat)))
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```