# Replacing plot number with sequential numbers using R, each plot has differing number of rows

Tags: r

I need to rename my plots with sequential numbers in R, but each plot has a different number of rows. How can I assign a new sequential plot number taking this into account?

I'm sorry, I don't know how to make a reproducible example. In the following table, some plots have no data so the numbering (column 'Plotn') is not sequential. I want to create a new column exactly like column 'Plotn1'. Perhaps it's a simple question but I've looked high and low and can't find an answer. Thank you.

```
Plotn  Species              Diameter Plotn1
1      Eucalyptus regnans   10       1
1      Eucalyptus obliqua   30       1
1      Eucalyptus obliqua   12       1
1      Eucalyptus obliqua   34       1
4      Eucalyptus regnans   45       2
5      Eucalyptus regnans   34       3
5      Eucalyptus obliqua   34       3
5      Eucalyptus regnans   22       3
6      Eucalyptus obliqua   34       4
6      Eucalyptus obliqua   33       4
```

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(x))` in base R I think - related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189967/how-do-i-preserve-continuous-1-2-3-n-ranking-notation-when-ranking-in-r/36191113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `dense_rank` method in `dplyr` that works in this case:

```
dplyr::dense_rank(df$Plotn)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

Or `frank` from `data.table`:

```
data.table::frank(df$Plotn, ties.method = "dense")
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4
```